# Error when migrating WordPress database to new server

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, mariadb

When migrating a WordPress database to a new server it get the the error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 194036: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> The dynamic response body size is over the limit, the response will be trunca' at line 413

I've tried both importing it in phpMyAdmin and also command line with the following command:

`mysql -uroot -p******* sout_travel < yY8tB9M7SaUz2P.sql`

I really don't know much about MySQL or MariaDB in this case. I'd appreciate if someone could shed a light...

*Source Server Specs:*

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04
Protocol version: 10
User: yY8tB9M7SaUz2P@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

LiteSpeed
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.0.33-13+bionic
```

---

*Destination Server Specs:*

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

LiteSpeed
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 7.2.30-1+bionic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL file (yY8tB9M7SaUz2P.sql) seems to be invalid. Open it with your favorite text editor and you'll probably find the text towards end of the file:

> The dynamic response body size is over the limit, the response will be trunca

Sounds like the process that generates the .sql file for you is being interrupted and can't complete, thus leaving the file invalid. If I had to guess, and I have to, that's part of the error message explaining what's the issue generating the SQL file. Your problem isn't loading the SQL file, but generating it.

Comment: Here is the last line of the file:

"$the web server. The limit is set in the key 'maxDynRespSize' located in the tuning section of the server configuration, and labeled 'max dynamic response body size'."

Comment: The file was generated in phpMyAdmin. I went there to export it.